# What does 0.2104 + 0.0000i mean in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

Some results in MATLAB seem very strange,

I get a vector of numbers like this:

```
0.2104 + 0.0000i
0.8404 + 0.0000i
0.2564 + 0.0000i
...
```

How can I convert these to a normal set of numbers?

I am completing maximum likelihood estimation and recording the p-values

here is a longer list of numbers out of my 5000

```
0.210375413 0.210375412872214 + 0.00000000000000i
0.053300966 0.0533009655998162 + 0.00000000000000i
0.569707287 0.569707286911292 + 0.00000000000000i
0.789479544 0.789479543799722 + 0.00000000000000i
0.792401416 0.792401416159656 + 0.00000000000000i
0.449510767 0.449510766546419 + 0.00000000000000i
0.967223276 0.967223275937553 + 0.00000000000000i
0.365126323 0.365126322610076 + 0.00000000000000i
0.572278247 0.572278247118208 + 0.00000000000000i
0.462192501 0.462192500844107 + 0.00000000000000i
0.891594566 0.891594565688343 + 0.00000000000000i
0.509256161 0.509256160918297 + 0.00000000000000i
0.195843938 0.195843938121061 + 0.00000000000000i
0.446937982 0.446937981596096 + 0.00000000000000i
0.715944643 0.715944642525015 + 0.00000000000000i
0.041095144 0.0410951439103705 + 0.00000000000000i
0.565493597 0.565493596672335 + 0.00000000000000i
0.110642354 0.110642353871931 + 0.00000000000000i
0.538977891 0.538977891429440 + 0.00000000000000i
0.633743323 0.633743322903976 + 0.00000000000000i
0.573735606 0.573735606007466 + 0.00000000000000i
0.776896023 0.776896022759461 + 0.00000000000000i
0.685299218 0.685299218035155 + 0.00000000000000i
0.273675891 0.273675891163331 + 0.00000000000000i
0.713439449 0.713439449399772 + 0.00000000000000i
0.778393872 0.778393872231057 + 0.00000000000000i
0.291038278 0.291038277535648 + 0.00000000000000i
1   0.999999999954056 - 750325.850663069i
0.884944383 0.884944383017724 + 0.00000000000000i
0.202998566 0.202998565584345 + 0.00000000000000i
```

It is only this one number `0.999999999954056 - 750325.850663069i` in the entire 5000 that seems off. Can I just ignore the imaginary part there?

Comment: Those are just [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). The imaginary part is very small, so with the default number of decimal digits (four) it is shown as `0`. Try `format long` to see more decimal digits

Comment: If you only want to keep the real part of those complex number you can use `real()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). I assume you want real numbers. You can do that using the function `real()`. `real()` will capture the "real" part of the complex number, a number that is made up by real and imaginary parts, as `real+imaginary`, often the imaginary part labelled as `i` so you don't think it a sum.

However, note: If this is the output of some computation, its likely that the maths you are doing are resulting in imaginary/complex numbers (e.g. `sqrt(-1)` results in `1i` or just `i`). By your lack of knowledge of what complex numbers are and surprise at finding them,  I suspect that the maths that lead to those results are not supposed to return complex numbers, and there is a high likelihood that you have a bug in your code.

Comment: @user30609 I insist: do not blindly use `real()`, please go back and check your code, if imaginary parts appear in non-complex maths, it just means you have a bug. There should not be there unless expected.

Comment: @user30609 no you can not use real and ignore that. The fact that you get complex numbers is a symptom of bad code, you can not just ignore it because it happens in one number! All of the maths can be wrong, they can be just wrong and not cause complex numbers! Do please re-check your maths and input data.